Is it possible to set up an OAI that would allow Cloudfront to read files with ACL set to Private?
When users upload their files to our S3 they set the ACL to S3CannedACL.Private.
While setting up Cloudfront to this bucket, I have created an OAI, and added the following permission in this S3 bucket:
{
     "Sid": "123",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity CLOUDFRONTID"},
     "Action": "s3:GetObject",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
}

However, I get Access Denied, like so:
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>ReqID</RequestId>
<HostId>HostId</HostId>
</Error>

I have also tried setting up OAC with the same result.
We do not have Bucket Owner is an Object Owner enabled as AWS support advised us that this will break the client where the ACLs are set on an object level during the upload.
Is there a way to give Cloudfront access without changing the client?
